# express route: doesn't render the pug file

Tags: express, pug

I am trying to get the form data in express through pug.But the route doesn't render the pug form.Following is the code:

```
router.get('/add', function(req, res) {
    res.render('crud/add');
});
```

Comment: I would recommend that you read this guide: https://itnext.io/pug-js-to-make-your-life-easier-with-html-templates-9c62273626e0

Comment: The link is helpful..but where i'm going wrong? i have placed the pug file in crud/add folder

Comment: You're not passing any data into the render function.  This is covered in the Pug getting started page and in that article as a first step.  Please also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was that i mentioned the view folder name instead of route name.MY BIG MISTAKE...! I am quite new to express and pug